# C - Using fgetc on a write file

Tags: c, io, fopen

Say we have a file pointer like this:

```
FILE *output = fopen("test.out", "w");
```

After writing to it, I want to read it using fgetc

However when I do:

```
char c1 = fgetc(output);
```

and then I print out c1 I get that c1 equals -1 which means there was an error in fgetc. Is it because I opened the file using "w"?

How can I read and write from the same file in the same function?

Comment: You should not use `char` type to store return value of `fgetc`. Return type is `int` and you aren't able to distiguish a value of `255` from `EOF` if you only have a character.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to both read and write the file, you should open it in write/update mode (ie pass “w+” to the mode argument instead of just “w”)

Also be sure to do a frewind() or fseek() before trying to read from the file, otherwise you’ll be trying to read past the end of the file’s data.

Comment: Not only trying to read past end of file. Switching from write to read without an intervening successful seek produces undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can't read from a write-only file. Open the file for read/write access using `"w+"` instead.

Also, after you write to the file, you have to seek backwards with `fseek()` before you can then read what you previously wrote.